# Why won't this code work, using an arduino uno, an sr04 ultrasound sensor and 9 leds?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to map the output of the ultrasound sensor to 9 leds using the following code, for some reason when I upload the code the leds all stay of and I don't even get a reading trough the serial monitor. I have tried similar code before, but without the leds, and that worked flawlessly.

```
const int trigPin = 13;
const int echoPin = 12;
const int maxRange = 300;
const int minRange = 0;
const int delayTime = 300;
const int ledPins[] = {10, 9, 8, 7 ,6, 5, 4, 3, 2};
const int ledCount = 9;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin (9600);
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    for(int thisLed = 0; thisLed < ledCount; thisLed = thisLed++){
        pinMode(ledPins[thisLed], OUTPUT); 
    }
}

void loop() {
    long duration;

    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);        // this alinea triggers the sensor
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);  // stores lenght of returned pulse

    long distance = duration/58.2;

    if (distance > maxRange){
        Serial.println("Out of range");
        delay(delayTime);
    }
    else if (distance < minRange){
        Serial.println("Out of range");
        delay(delayTime);
    }
    else {
        Serial.print(distance);
        Serial.println(" cm");      
        delay(delayTime);
    }

    constrain(distance, minRange, maxRange);
    int usedLed = map(distance, minRange, maxRange, 0, ledCount);

    for(int thisLed = 0; thisLed < usedLed; thisLed++){
        digitalWrite(ledPins[thisLed], HIGH); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are running an infinite loop in the code below, inside the setup function:

```
for(int thisLed = 0; thisLed < ledCount; thisLed = thisLed++){
   pinMode(ledPins[thisLed], OUTPUT); 
}
```

This piece of code `thisLed = thisLed++` yields undefined behavior according to the Clause 6.5 §2 of the [C99 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value
>   to be stored.

In order to fix that replace `thisLed = thisLed++` by `thisLed++`

Comment: Thank you so much! It's still doesn't display the distance on the leds, and the program randomly stops after getting some readings, but at least it's doing something now.